# How to make a fully responsive Google Maps inserted in website

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm putting an embedded Google Map side by side with a responsive image inside a div. I want the map to be the same size as the image always, and resize as it does.
This is my code, and the map looks really small.

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid12-6 no-gutter">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MoFU-ybvlUw/TsXyHlX2AlI/AAAAAAAAARQ/kqXxZ8SquX8/s1600/la+fotolego.JPG" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="grid12-6 no-gutter">
  <div class="map-container">
    <div class="mapa">
      <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=manquehue%20norte%201255&t=&z=14&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this
[image]

Comment: Show us youre best attempt. Does CSS for iframe not work?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you will have to keep your parent as a display: flex; and the childrens as flex-items or inline.